# offset.Top in relative container with pageY calculations

Tags: javascript

I got a script that is a direction aware hover. It work's great but the thing is, I have to use relative container. If I use one, the calculations got all wrong because offsetTop counts from the container and not body. When I use pageY and pageX in the calculations I get wrong result.

```
y = (ev.pageY - obj.offsetTop  - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
x = (ev.pageX - obj.offsetLeft - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
```

I got fiddle with console.log:
https://jsfiddle.net/zvny953x/

What I need to achieve is, obj.offsetTop and obj.offsetLeft will ignore relative container. Guess it's not possible so I have to calculate it's position according to element position in the whole document not only container

Let say I got that container really down in the webpage and it's what console.log says:

pageY: 2682
pageX: 1050
obj.offsetTop: 235
obj.offsetLeft: 101

What it should look like:

pageY: 2765
pageX: 91
obj.offsetTop: 2682
obj.offsetLeft: 101

Hope you get the point.

Comment: ps. I added rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect(); and X is working great, Y doesn't work. Still counts the height from container not document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this.

It's what I added:

```
 rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
    clientTop = document.documentElement.clientTop || obj.clientTop || 0,
    scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || obj.scrollTop),
    x = (ev.pageX - rect.left - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
    y = (ev.pageY - rect.top - scrollTop - clientTop - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
```